# No logro mostrar el resultado de una consulta

Tags: php

No logro mostrar el resultado de la consulta, quiero mostrarlo en un objeto json.

```
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select CONCAT(usuarios.apellidop,' ',usuarios.apellidom,' ',usuarios.nombres) as nombre,
    usuarios.foto,usuarios.user,asistencia.asistio from asistencia
    inner join usuarios on usuarios.user = asistencia.codigoest
    where asistencia.codigoasig = '".$s."' and asistencia.fecha= '".$fecha."' order by usuarios.apellidop ");
$stmt->execute();
```

Antes usaba:

```
$sql="select CONCAT(usuarios.apellidop,' ',usuarios.apellidom,' ',usuarios.nombres) as nombre,
    usuarios.foto,usuarios.user,asistencia.asistio from asistencia
    inner join usuarios on usuarios.user = asistencia.codigoest
    where asistencia.codigoasig = '$s' and asistencia.fecha= '$fecha' order by usuarios.apellidop ";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $data[] = array('nombre'=>$row['nombre'],'foto'=>base64_encode($row['foto']),'codigo'=>$row['user'],'asistio'=>$row['asistio']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Estas usando PDO , mira la documentación de php. Hay lo encuentras. Estabas usando mysqli y ahora usas pdo , cambia la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de mostrar los datos :

```
$conn = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);
$consulta = $conn->query($sql);
$consulta->fetchAll(); // muestra los datos
```

Si te fijas estoy usando fetchAll() , ala que le asocio la conexión en PDO , donde realizo la consulta.

Al ser una búsqueda en PDO , tienes que saber que tienes que usar las interrogantes.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select CONCAT(usuarios.apellidop,' ',usuarios.apellidom,' ',usuarios.nombres) as nombre,
    usuarios.foto,usuarios.user,asistencia.asistio from asistencia
    inner join usuarios on usuarios.user = asistencia.codigoest
    where asistencia.codigoasig = '".?."' and asistencia.fecha= ? order by usuarios.apellidop ");
```

Como en elejemplo siguiente

```
/* Ejecutar una sentencia preparada vinculando varialbes de PHP */
$calorías = 150;
$color = 'red';
$gsent = $gbd->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$gsent->bindValue(1, $calorías, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$gsent->bindValue(2, $color, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$gsent->execute();
```

Más info en la [documentación de pdo de php](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)